# Flashback archive is inserting data even no data changed after update statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2, flashback

I have enabled Flashback archive on a table. Oracle inserts data in Flash back even if no record is changed in the table after updating a record.

For example

```
Update Dept set DEPTNO = '10' WHERE DEPTNO = '10';
```

When i use flashback query to extract all records it shows 1 record is added.

```
SELECT  versions_startscn, versions_starttime,
       versions_endscn, versions_endtime,
       versions_xid, versions_operation,
       dept.*
  FROM dept
  VERSIONS BETWEEN  SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE;
```

Is there any setting for FlashBack Archive that it store only changed records.?

Comment: Usually you'd expect no-change updates to be rare (i.e. why would a user click "Save" after making no changes?), so generally it's faster to just let Oracle save every change - otherwise you'd have to wear the extra performance cost of comparing each and every column with the previous record.